# how to display data from fasta file in jtable

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable, filereader

my code is:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

import org.biojavax.SimpleNamespace;
import org.biojavax.bio.seq.RichSequence;
import org.biojavax.bio.seq.RichSequenceIterator;
import org.biojava.bio.seq.*;
import org.biojava.bio.seq.io.*;
import org.biojava.bio.symbol.*;

public class ReadGES_BJ1_6{
    /* 
     * ReadGES_BJ1_6.java - A pretty simple demo program to read a sequence file
     * with a known format using Biojavax extension found in BJ1.6. 
     * 
     * You only need to provide a file as args[0]
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        SimpleNamespace ns = null;

        try{
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
            ns = new SimpleNamespace("biojava");

            // You can use any of the convenience methods found in the BioJava 1.6 API
            RichSequenceIterator rsi = RichSequence.IOTools.readFastaDNA(br,ns);

            // Since a single file can contain more than a sequence, you need to iterate over
            // rsi to get the information.
            while(rsi.hasNext()){
                RichSequence rs = rsi.nextRichSequence();
                //Sequence seq = stream.nextSequence();
                int gc = 0;
                for (int pos = 1; pos <= rs.length(); ++pos) {
                Symbol sym = rs.symbolAt(pos);
                if (sym == DNATools.g() || sym == DNATools.c())
                ++gc;

                }       

    System.out.println(rs.getName()+"\t"+rs.length()+"\t"+((gc * 100.0) / rs.length())/*+"\t"+rs.seqString()*/);
         //System.out.println(ns);
                /*System.out.println(rs.seqString());
                System.out.println(rs.length());
                System.out.println(((gc * 100.0) / rs.length()));*/

            }
        }
        catch(Exception be){
            be.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

it gives output as:

```
contig00001   586   52.38%
contig00002   554   62.45%
```

my question is how to display above output exactly in three coloumns in jtable
pls help?

Answer (score 1):

please read tutorial about [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), JTable [examples](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Table.htm) and your File output you have to add to the `Object [][]` or [`Vector<Vector<Object>>`](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/0600__Vector.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the data in your TableModel, [Table Format Renderers](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/) will help you format the 3rd column with a % sign.